# Expieriencing Block\Tick Lag

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I entered a new game in hardcore mode and when I tried to mine wood, it took a long time to actually drop the item. It would spawn back and take FOREVER to drop. How do you fix it?

Answer (score 11):

This happens when the server is lagging. If you are playing locally, in single player, it's very likely that your computer is either doing something tasking or just can't handle the server. If you're playing multiplayer, either your internet connection is lagging or the server is being slow.

The only way to fix it is to either play on a different server or get a faster computer.

Comment: Well, checking how much memory Minecraft can use compared to how much the system actually has might be a nice step before buying a whole new computer :)